# Can disable pushing branches that don't exist in the GitHub repo?

Tags: git, github

Such as the title, I hope someone is able to push the branch only if it has been created in the GitHub repo.

Comment: Interesting question, though I'm curious about the use case. Typically if don't want people creating their own branches, you also don't want them to push to existing ones without a PR.

Comment: I'm a newcomer to GitHub, not sure if I'm right.
If I manage a team, allow them to create a new branch locally, then someone may create a new branch locally by mistake or in private.  He pushes this new branch to GitHub, then others may be confused about the new one.  So I hope only the team leader has permission to create a new branch in GitHub.

Comment: Github branches can be ephemeral and usually projects have many of them. Usually there would be one or more "important" branches which you would want to protect by requiring pull requests. Then developers would create a new branch for each task that they're working on, create a pull request when it's ready to be merged and then delete it after it has been approved and merged.

Comment: Regarding this: "He pushes this new branch to GitHub, then others may be confused about the new one." I would recommend using a branch naming convention. At my company we have been using `user/first.last/Issue12345-some-short-description`. We know who made the branch and also that it is going to likely get rewritten so we shouldn't base our own work off of it. All shared branches (e.g. `develop`, `release`, `master`, `main`) are protected and require PRs. In this way no one ever gets confused when they see new "user" branches.

Comment: That being said, sometimes people mess up and push branches that violate the convention, e.g. `test-branch`. I usually look at the commits to see who did it, (or the push history if needed), and tell the person to rename their branch. It doesn't happen often enough to try to prevent it.